# sqlite: how to get row id of the row that has the update button on it?

Tags: html, node.js, sqlite, electron

I have sqlite3 database with `lastdate` column then I query this column and put it into HTML table and dynamically add an update button to every HTML table row.

Also by clicking update button another page will open with input field `type="date"` and another update button on it and when I click this update button a function query the id of the row and update the corresponding column value in the database.

However, this function always update the last row whatever row I click. My function is as following:

```
ipcMain.on("update-hide",function(event, inptData){
    var sqlDB = new sqlite3.Database('./database.sqlite')
    var dateupdate = inptData.toString();
    var id_1;

    sqlDB.serialize(() => {
    sqlDB.serialize(() => {
        var n = 0;
        sqlDB.each("SELECT * FROM info", function(err, row, i) {
                let data = {id: row.ID,};
                var id = data.id;
                id_1 = id;
            }, ()=> {
                let listOfData = [dateupdate,id_1];
                sqlDB.run(`UPDATE infoSET lastdate = (?)WHERE id=(?)`, listOfData, function(err) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log(`Row(s) updated: ${this.changes}`);
                    }
                    sqlDB.close();
                });
            });
        });
    });
})
```

So how to query the ID of the row that I click the update button on it?

**Note:**

I'm using electron framework.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question but do you need a way to get the row id when only HTML is available?

Comment: i need to get row ID of the row that has update button. In other words i want to update lastdate of the row with value from input field when clicking update button of that row @AlexCharters

Answer (score 1):

I guess maybe you should pass the row id into the another page and use get method to get the id from the url something like

$ids = $result["ID"];

index.php?id='.$ids.' //This will get the corresponding row id of the column you have to store the row id into ids

index.php?id=1  //url

$id = $_GET["id"]; // get the id

Comment: Welcome to SO! While your answer would be valid in PHP, please note that OP does not use PHP but JavaScript within electron.